# What are the methods to increase the dimension of a feature space?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

Is there a way to increase the number of dimensions through feature transformation in machine learning? If so what are the techniques involved?

Comment: One example is the kernel trick for SVMs: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-kernel-trick-c98cdbcaeb3f

Comment: A useful term of art is "basis expansion."

Answer (score 4):

Square them.

Log them.

Multiply them.

Multiply their logs.

Log their products.

Take Fourier or wavelet transforms of time series data.

Any function of your set of features is a possible additional feature to include instead of or along with the original features. Some such functions will be more useful than others, yes, but pretty much any function of your features included as an additional feature will increase the dimension of your feature space.

Comment: ... take interactions between pairs, triplets or more of your predictors, or of transformed predictors. Also, do spline or harmonic transformations, the latter especially to capture periodicity.

Answer (score 0):

A feature transformation can be "learned" by fitting a neural network. For example, if the original features $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are mapped to one of $k$ classes, the mapping may be modeled using a neural network $f$ with one hidden layer (omitting bias parameters):

$$
\begin{equation*}
f(x; W_1, W_2) = \sigma(W_2 \text{relu}(W_1x))
\end{equation*}
\\
\text{where }  W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{h \times d}, W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times h}.
$$

You may very well set $h$ to be greater than $d$. After fitting $f$ on a bunch of training data, the function

$$
\begin{equation*}
g(x; W_1) = W_1x
\end{equation*}
$$

outputs a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{h}$ which may encode information about how a given $x$ relates to the $k$ classes. This information may be treated as a more abstract or "transferrable" representation of $x$ for future tasks.

[Word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) is a concrete example of this idea: an $x$ is a "one-hot" vector indicating which word in the vocabulary it is, and a neural network is learned to (literally) assign any word to a vector. This vector abstractly represents something about the "meaning" of that word. (In a literal sense, a Word2vec model doesn't necessarily increase the dimensionality of the original one-hot vector. But it illustrates the point that transformations to a vector space with any dimension can be learned.) These vectors can be used to numerically encode wordy features in external datasets, or to initialize the first layer of a language model.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways. A classic example is polynomial expansions - you take all powers of your input variables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem from 1885)

Fourier series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)

These are roughly equivalent to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem of neural networks.

Note that being able to represent a function doesn't mean you have "learnt" the function.

eg the parity function: 1 if the (integer) number is odd or 0 if the number is odd.
This can be represented on any *fixed* interval eg [0,100] by a suitable polynomial). however, there is no generalisation -eg train on [0,50] test on [51,100]. Similarly with tree based methods (trees/random forest/xgboost etc).